# PHP Cookies redirect to wrong role

Tags: php, cookies

good day...
i have some problem here and hopefully someone can help

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['role'])== "admin")
{ echo $_COOKIE['username']; 
header("location: admin/adminUI.php");
}
elseif(isset($_COOKIE['role']) == "customer")
{ echo $_COOKIE['username']; 
header("location: customer/customerUI.php");
}
```

the cookies right in PHP
i set this earlier

```
setcookie ("username", $username, time()+3600,"/");
setcookie ("role", $role, time()+3600,"/");
```

but either i choose the role = admin or customer, the header will also redirect to admin page...
may i know what is the problem?

thanks

Comment: You should read the manual for http://www.php.net/isset again

Comment: And you should never ever bind privileges to a simple cookie value like this. This is outside of your control and I can simply change the cookie "role" in my browser to "admin" and I am admin :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If output anything before the header() directive, like you're doing with echo, the redirect won't work at all. You need to remove the echo so that redirect you're specifying in the header works.

Also, isset() only checks if a variable is **set**, not if it **equals another string**. Therefore, this check:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['role'])== "admin")
```

is wrong, and should be changed to something like:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['role']) && $_COOKIE['role'] == "admin")
```

Finally, as mentioned,  you should **never ever ever** base checking of priviledges depending on the value of a cookie, as these can be changed by the users using simple client side tools. Use sessions instead.

Check the PHP session handling page for more info:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Here's a relatively straightforward example of how to authenticate users in PHP, using sessions and a MySQL database:

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Answer (score 0):

First, trusting a cookie -- which is easily edited by a user -- is like hanging the key to your apartment on you front door in plain sight. It's kinda worse than having no security at all.

That said, you shouldn't `echo` before `header()` (at least not without output buffering). Read the [notes in the `header()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). Also, echoing anything before redirect is meaningless.

Last, but not least, the `isset()` issue, as Filippos beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to use COOKIE is such cases. A more better approach would be to use SESSION variables. Also there is not point of using echo as you are redirecting in the very next statement. Last but not the least, you cannot use '==' with isset function.

Go through this  [Isset Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

This right code:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['role'])&&$_COOKIE['role']== "admin")
{ 
  header("location: admin/adminUI.php");
}
elseif(isset($_COOKIE['role'])&&$_COOKIE['role'] == "customer")
{ 
  header("location: customer/customerUI.php");
}
```